# Set of real $a$ so that the inequality is defined but isn't true for a real $x$

Tags: logarithms, quadratics

$$x(x-\sqrt {4+\log_a7})\lt \log_7 \frac a{49}$$

I reach the interval $(0,1)$ after looking for the discriminant of the quadratic to be less than zero. However, the solution in the book is an interval that includes $\sqrt 7$, which by hand you can figure out is a solution. Am I wrong? Is it the book? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$x(x-\sqrt{4+\log_a7}) < \log_7 a - \log_7 49 =\frac1{\log_a 7} - 2$$

$$
x^2 - x\sqrt{4+\log_a 7} - \frac 1 {\log_a 7} + 2 < 0.
$$

\begin{align}
\text{discriminant} & = (4+\log_a 7) - 4\left( - \frac 1 {\log_a 7} + 2 \right) = \log_a 7 + \frac 4 {\log_a 7} - 4 \\[12pt]
& = \begin{cases}
\left( \sqrt{\log_a 7} - \dfrac 2 {\sqrt{\log_a 7}} \right)^2 & \text{if }\log_a 7>0, \\[10pt]
-\left( \sqrt{-\log_a 7} + \dfrac 2 {\sqrt{-\log_a 7}} \right)^2 & \text{if }\log_a 7<0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
When the discriminant is negative then the inequality will have no solution, and that happens when $\log_a 7<0$, i.e. if $a<1$.

[To be continued, maybe${}\,\ldots\,{}$]

Comment: This is indeed what I got. So the book has it wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure . . . I may come back and finish this a bit later . . .

Comment: Is it $x(x-\sqrt {4+\log_ab})\lt \log_b \frac a{b^2}$ some "generalization" of the question?

Answer (score 1):

For $a=\sqrt 7$ one has
$$x\left(x-\sqrt{4+\log_{\sqrt 7}7}\right)\lt \log_7{\frac{\sqrt 7}{49}},$$
i.e.
$$x(x-\sqrt 6)\lt -\frac 32,$$
i.e.
$$2x^2-2\sqrt 6\ x+3\lt 0.$$
However, this is not true because
$$2x^2-2\sqrt 6\ x+3=2\left(x-\frac{\sqrt 6}{2}\right)^2\ge 0.$$

Comment: So... I am correct?

Comment: @JohnDoe: I think I misread your question? Anyway, what I wrote is what I want to say:)

Comment: Oh welp. Right. Damn. How do you solve this then?

Comment: @JohnDoe: The discriminant has to be positive (excluding $0$), so the answer will be $0\lt a\lt 1$ or $a=\sqrt 7$  as you wrote in the question, right?

Comment: Nope. The solution is $(0,7^{-1/4}),{7^{1/2}}$ I believe I got it after tinkering around some. The problrm is the discriminant has to be less than zero or both of the solutions have to be positive or the one solution has to be positive I believe.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Ah, I see. First of all, we have $4+\log_a7\ge 0,a\gt 0,a\not=1$. Then, we have $0\lt a\lt 1$ and $a=\sqrt 7$. These will lead the answer you wrote.

Comment: @JohnDoe: The solution should be $0\lt a\color{red}{\le} 7^{-1/4}$ or $a=\sqrt 7$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine when an inequality
$$
x(x-A)<B
$$
has no solutions. It becomes
$$
x^2-Ax-B<0
$$
and the discriminant should be nonpositive, so that the quadratic only takes on nonnegative values. This means
$$
A^2+4B\le0
$$
Now $A=\sqrt{4+\log_a7}$ and $B=\log_7a-2$. By the change of basis formula, $\log_a7=1/\log_7a$, so we can set $k=\log_7a$. Note that a condition is $a>0$, $a\ne1$. Moreover we need $4+\log_a7\ge0$, but I'll return later to this.

Our condition now reads
$$
4+\frac{1}{k}+4k-8\le0
$$
or
$$
\frac{4k^2-4k+1}{k}\le0
$$
that gives $k<0$, because the numerator is $(2k-1)^2$, which is nonnegative, or $k=1/2$.

Thus one condition is $\log_7a<0$, that is, $a<1$, or $a=\sqrt{7}$

Now we return to
$$
4+\frac{1}{k}\ge0
$$
If $k<0$, this means $4k+1\le0$, that is $k<-1/4$ or $0<a\le1/\sqrt[4]{7}$; it is satisfied for $k=1/2$. So the final answer is
$$
0<a\le\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{7}}\text{ or } a=\sqrt{7}
$$

Comment: Somewhere you switched up a sign. Apart from that and not including the possible double solution, this is definitely correct

Comment: @JohnDoe You're right! I'll fix it. What possible double solution are you hinting at?

Comment: The function has to be strictly negative (or the opposite in this case) which mean it can be 0.

Comment: @JohnDoe If it must be strictly negative, it can't be $0$.

Comment: A quadratic function can only touch the x axis when the discriminant is 0.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, of course; but your original inequality has $<$, not $\le$. If you allow the discriminant to be $0$ you may get a solution and you want none.

Comment: The solution will as it turns out, be larger than 0, so it plays into the solution.

Comment: Welp. Equal to zero. Still not a solution and thus a solution

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: We are looking for when for all x, an expression will not be true. It just so happens that the expression is a quadratic function being compared to zero. If it is <0, it is true, so all cases where for every x, f(x) $\ge 0$ works. A function touching the x axis but never going negative works for this

Comment: @JohnDoe You're reasoning the wrong way. A quadratic $x^2+px+q$ only takes on negative values *if and only if* its discriminant is negative. If the discriminant is zero, the quadratic will assume the value $0$. In this case the situation is complicated by the fact that $p$ and $q$ may not be defined for all values of $a$, but this has no consequence.

Comment: Ill adress this tomorrow, idk anymore. All i know is my book includes sqrt7. You can see that it is definitely a solution yet not in your interval

Comment: @JohnDoe Now I see my mistake! Yes, I was reasoning wrongly. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: @egreg: I think the final result should be $0\lt a\le 7^{1/4}$ or $a=\sqrt 7$. I think we have to find $a$ such that the inequality is defined but *isn't* true for any $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @mathlove No: as John Doe observed, we want that *no solution* to $x(x-A)<B$ exists, that is, $x(x-A)\ge B$ for all $x$.

Comment: @egreg: I had a typo. I meant $0\lt a\le 7^{-1/4}$ or $a=\sqrt 7$. For $a=7^{-1/4}$, for example, $x(x-A)\ge B$ for all $x$. So, the final result at least has to include $a=7^{-1/4}$, I think.